# Parsing dynamic arabic character xml in python

Tags: python, xml-parsing

This is the code. However, this code can only parse 4 characters of Arabian only. I want it to parse dynamically. So, the number of characters does not matter. Therefore, it can parse 1 character, 2 character or more based on the number of existing characters.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os, glob
import csv
from time import time

#read xml path
xml_path = glob.glob('D:\1. Thesis FINISH!!!\*.xml')

#create file declaration for saving the result
file = open("parsing.csv","w")
#file = open("./%s" % ('parsing.csv'), 'w')

#create variable of starting time
t0=time()

#create file header
file.write('wordImage_id'+'|'+'paw1'+'|'+'paw2'+'|' + 'paw3' + '|' + 'paw4' + '|'+'font_size'+'|'+'font_style'+
           '|'+'font_name'+'|'+'specs_effect'+'|'+'specs_height'+'|'+'specs_height'
           +'|'+'specs_width'+'|'+'specs_encoding'+'|'+'generation_filtering'+
           '|'+'generation_renderer'+'|'+'generation_type' + '\n')

for doc in xml_path:
    print 'Reading file - ', os.path.basename(doc)
    tree = ET.parse(doc)
    #tree = ET.parse('D:\1. Thesis FINISH!!!\Image_14_AdvertisingBold_13.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()

    #get wordimage id

    image_id = root.attrib['id']

    #get paw 1 and paw 2
    paw1 = root[0][0].text
    paw2 = root[0][1].text
    paw3 = root[0][2].text
    paw4 = root[0][3].text

    #get properties of font
    for font in root.findall('font'):
        size = font.get('size')
        style = font.get('fontStyle')
        name = font.get('name')

    #get properties of specs
    for specs in root.findall('specs'):
        effect = specs.get('effect')
        height = specs.get('height')
        width = specs.get('width')
        encoding = specs.get('encoding')


    #get properties for generation
    for generation in root.findall('generation'):
        filtering = generation.get('filtering')
        renderer = generation.get('renderer')
        types = generation.get('type')

    #save the result in csv
    file.write(image_id + '|' + paw1 + '|' + paw2 + '|' + paw3 + '|' + paw4 + '|' + size + '|' +
               style + '|' + name + '|' + effect + '|' + height + '|'
               + width + '|' + encoding + '|' + filtering + '|' + renderer               + '|' + types + '\n')

#close the file
file.close()

#print time execution
print("process done in %0.3fs." % (time() - t0))
```